# how to extract the functions from a c++ header file with haskell?

Tags: c++, parsing, haskell, header

i need to get all the functions from a c++ header file with haskell (not methods only functions), i need the input parameters and the return type also the method name.

how could i realise this? olny with regex? or must i write a whole parser (bottom-up or top-down)?

Comment: Are you writing a tool to parse the header, or are you trying to generate bindings from Haskell to those functions (e.g. FFI bindings with c2hs)?

Comment: Why has it got to be done with Haskell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extract all the function declarations from a header file, you'll need a parser, not a regex. Parsers for C++ are hard to come by, but luckily we have some:

- [Language.C](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-c), for parsing C files
- [LibClang](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/LibClang), for parsing C++ files

Using either of these you'll be able to robustly process C or C++ headers, and extract declarations as Haskell data types, for further processing.

Comment: would like to use the LibCland but get these build failure because i use ghc7: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/LibClang/0.0.9/logs/failure/ghc-7.0

Comment: Hackage doesn't have the C library, libclang, installed, hence the failures. As long as you install libclang (the C library) first, you should be fine.

Comment: Too bad there's no way for Cabal/Hackage to realize that the C library being missing renders the results inconclusive, huh?

Answer (score 1):

If you do decide to parse them, I recommend you use [Parsec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec) and try to see if anybody else has already done it.

But, there are many C++ parsers already out there - I recommend you use one of them and interface with its output.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a program called [cgen](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cgen) that generates C bindings to C++ libraries, and it parses C++ headers (using Parsec) and collects the function data like you describe. It's ridiculously far from being a complete C++ parser, but it can parse some simple header files - like this [example](http://anttisalonen.github.com/cgen/animals.html).

It's not a library, though, so you may need to adapt the code to fit your needs (and if you make any improvements, do send me a patch). You can find the relevant code at [github](https://github.com/anttisalonen/cgen/tree/master/src), particularly the modules HeaderParser and HeaderData.